# popen not working correctly on sunos5

Tags: c++

I have program to find emacs path using `which command`
if it does not find emacs then i find emacs in `$PATH` variable.
Lets my system have emacs
then below program is giving output correct **but it is sourcing .cshrc file** I dont know why?

```
/* getenv example: getting path */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[256];
    const char *command = "which emacs 2>&1";
    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(0);
    }
    string path1;
    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        path1 += path;
    }
    cout<<"orignal path after which command = "<<path1<<endl;
    /* close */
    bool found = true;
    std::string search="which:";
    char *tmp; 
    tmp = strstr(path1.c_str(),search.c_str()); 
    if (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        found = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        found = true;
    }
    if (found){
        cout<<"Found Emacs"<<endl;
        cout<<"path = "<<path1;
        string path2;
        for (int i=0; i < path1.length()-1; i++)
        {
            path2 += path1[i];
        }
        //path1[path1.length()-1]= " ";
        path2 += " -i";
        cout<<"final path = "<<path2<<endl;}
    else
        cout<<"Not found Emacs"<<endl;
    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is working on Linux but not on Sunos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SunOS` `which` command is a `csh` script that sources your `.cshrc` file as it searches csh aliases, which it could not do from outside csh. The linux `which` command is a posix shell script. They are different commands, operating in different ways.

It makes far more sense to search along the `PATH` environment variable than relying on the which command. The which command can turn into a shell built-in on certain shells (e.g. `zsh`), and operates in different ways depending on the operating system (I think the mac uses a binary).

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are finding emacs in you $PATH variable, all path variables are located in either ~/.cshrc or ~/.bashrc depending on whether or not you use csh or bash respectively.  You can see which shell you are using using the command ps.  Maybe you are using different shells in each OS.

Comment: I am using tcsh on SunoS as well as on Linux but i getting this problem on Sunos only.